# Accessing stored procedure in Linq-to-SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I'm using Linq-to-SQL query and using stored procedure in that. I'm getting error :

> Specified cast is not valid.

How to solve it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `TDetail.AMOUNT` values.

Your error is not when casting to an array, but rather in the `Convert.ToDouble(TDetail.AMOUNT)`.

Run your stored proc with those same arguments (in SSMS or Visual Studio), and try to determine which value in TDetail.AMOUNT is causing this problem.

You're seeing this exception being thrown when you cast to an array, but it would happen whenever you evaluated your LINQ query. It's nothing to do with `ToArray()`. It could be `ToList()`, and you'd find the same exception.